# Is calling conn.rollback redundant while doing transaction in jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, transactions

While this particular question has been asked multiple times already, but I am still unsure about it. My set up is something like this: I am using jdbc and have autocommit as false. Let's say I have 3 insert statements, I want to execute as a transaction followed by `conn.commit()`.

sample code:

```java
try {
    getConnection()
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    insertStatment() //#1
    insertStatment() //#2
    insertStatment() //#3, could throw an error
    conn.commit()
} catch(Sql exception) {
    conn.rollback() // why is it needed?
}
```

Say I have two scenarios

1. Either, there won't be any error and we will call `conn.commit()` and everything will be updated.
2. Say first two statements work fine but there is a error in the third one. So `conn.commit()` is not called and our database is in consistent state. So why do I need to call `conn.rollback()`?

I noticed that some people mentioned that rollback has an impact in case of connection pooling? Could anyone explain to me, how it will affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `rollback()` is still necessary. Not committing or rolling back a transaction might keep resources in use on the database (transaction handles, logs or record versions etc). Explicitly committing or rolling back makes sure those resources are released.

Not doing an explicit rollback may also have bad effects when you continue to use the connection and then commit. Changes successfully completed in the transaction (#1 and #2 in your example) will be persisted.

The [`Connection` apidoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) however does say *"If auto-commit mode has been disabled, the method commit must be called explicitly in order to commit changes; otherwise, database changes will not be saved."* which should be interpreted as: a `Connection.close()` causes a rollback. However I believe there have been JDBC driver implementations that used to commit on connection close.

The impact on connection pooling should not exist for **correct** implementations. Closing the logical connection obtained from the connection pool should have the same effect as closing a physical connections: an open transaction should be rolled back. However sometimes connection pools are not correctly implemented or have bugs or take shortcuts for performance reasons, all of which could lead to an open transaction being already started when you get handed a logical connection from a pool.

Therefor: be explicit in calling rollback.